# Composer: use branch dev-* in sub-dependencies

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I have 3 composer packages, A, B and C.

- A needs B and C
- B needs C

For my pipeline during a merge request of A, I need version of C with "dev-my-branch-name" but as B require C with tag release (X.Y.Z), composer is not able to install packages.

I try to use stability flag `@dev` but it doesn't work.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can "trick" package B with requiring package C in your main `composer.json` with:

```
"require": {
    "vendor/package-c": "dev-my-branch-name as x.y.z"
}
```

Use this with a grain of salt though, as this is not recommended for production use, only as a temporary measure.